# radix tree data structure insert strings

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to implement an insert method for the radix tree data structure and I dont know which graph (3.1 or 3.2) is the right one for the example in the image?

I appeciate any help.

[image]

Comment: I would argue that `3.2 a` is *more* correct than `3.1 a`, but not completely correct. The green nodes at the bottom of `3.2 a` should be "abf" and "abr", and have node under them with "abfg" and "abra".

Comment: They're both wrong.  3.2 would be correct if you change ab to ba

Comment: @MattTimmermans: Thanks I have changed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a radix tree, once you get to a node, you have to be able to decide the next branch to take based on the next unconsumed character.  That means that you will never have two branches from the same node that start with the same character.

In graph 3.1 both of the branches follwing "a" start with "b", so this is incorrect.

Also, adding a new string to a radix tree will change at most one existing edge.  You had to change two edges to make 3.1.

3.2 is correct - one edge is changed, and all branches from the same node start with different characters.